# Angular push to create table row

Tags: angular, collections, push

I'm new at Angular, so my problem is when I push a new object on a ngFor created table. The problem is when I write some text on the textbox and click on "+ Agregar", angular add a new row but erase the data of the others inputs. But if I add 4 rows, then write on the inputs some data and delete 1 row, after that if I add new rows the old data from the texboxt stay there

**Template**

```
<tr *ngFor="let presupuestolinea of this.presupuestolineas; let i = index">
<td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center">{{i+1}}</td>
<td class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" #lineadescripcion="ngModel" name="lineadescripcion" [(ngModel)]="presupuestolinea.lineadescripcion" class="form-control" /></td>
<td class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" #lineaprecio="ngModel" name="lineaprecio" [(ngModel)]="presupuestolinea.lineaprecio" class="form-control" /></td>
<td class="col-sm-1">
    <a title="Borrar" *ngIf="identity.role == 'ADMIN'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style="text-align: center;width: 100px" (click)="deleteLinea(i)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp;Eliminar
    </a>
</td>
```

**Component**

```
addLinea(index){
    let nuevoP = new Presupuestolinea(0,'','')
    this.presupuestolineas.push(nuevoP);
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8meE.jpg

Comment: Where's the closing `</tr>`?

Comment: You cannot use "this" within the HTML.And you have missed a closing </tr>.

Comment: I forgot the </tr> here, but is there...